# Angular ui router with angular loading bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use angular loading bar and I want to show it when state change.

This is the repo https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

Reference to this issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2260

This part of code is in run method of main module app:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    cfpLoadingBar.start();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    cfpLoadingBar.complete(); 
});
```

I have this selector

```
cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '.wrapper > section';
```

The problem is that the selector is in nested view and the $stateChangeStart starts before view is loaded so I got error from loading bar because it not found the selector.

This is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastChild' of undefined
    at Object._start [as start] (loading-bar.js:215)
    at app.js:253
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:16238)
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3140)
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.js:2318)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4473)
    at handleIfMatch (angular-ui-router.js:1822)
    at angular-ui-router.js:1877
    at check (angular-ui-router.js:1992)
    at update (angular-ui-router.js:2001)
```

Any solution??

Thanks
FS

Comment: what is the point of nesting the element in view if it's purpose is related to view changes?

Comment: also would be trivial to see if that element exists before calling the start method

Comment: Element exist but after state is change success!

Comment: No solution for this?

Comment: Yes, move the element out of `ui-view`

Comment: But for this effect I need to attach with this settings, now I see there is a pull request for this bug: https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/pull/244

Comment: so use a directive outside of the view